# p-test for parameter

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, p-value, parameterization

Statisticians, number magicians,

I was wondering what the best way is to check for the equality of two parameters including possibly a confidence interval and p-value.

$$H_0:\beta_1=\beta_2\vert\ \tilde{y}_1=\hat{\beta}_1\tilde{x}_1;\tilde{y}_2=\hat{\beta}_2\tilde{x}_2;n_1\not=n_2$$

Thanks,
Rik

Comment: There's not enough information here. What is known about the $x$ and $y$ variables? Is there really no error here (so that a single observed $x_1$ and $y_1$ will tell us $\beta_1$ exactly)?

Comment: Sorry they are not single observations, they are two different populations; so it is two regressions with no constant. I'm not sure what the right notation is. $x_1$ and $y_1$ are vectors...

Comment: Are you testing equality of regression coefficients?

Comment: Yes, but without a constant, only a slope...

Comment: Isn't this just like the text-book method but with the constant be zero?

Comment: If it's regression, I think you better have an error term. You should tell us the assumptions for that.

Comment: Not sure why there is no constant, I'm doing a problem for an engineering professor, I think it has to do with his model, I didn't really ask